# NodeJS Route not working. "Assignment to constant variable." Error

Tags: node.js, rest, ejs, nav

I am trying to set up a Shop page for my website. I have a navigation bar with 7 items. Each item works. They all work via a RestFUL API (Node server, routes, and controllers...). So I have it set up exactly the same for all pages. But for the shop page it won't work, not sure why. Thanks for all input.

Route
`

```
router.post('/addshopitem', encodedParser, function(req, res) {
  console.log("okay step 2");
  const name = req.body.name;
  const desc = req.body.desc;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const stock = req.body.stock;
  const createdby = req.body.createdby;

  console.log("okay step 2 almost");

  ShopController.add_item(req,res,name,desc,price,stock,createdby);

  console.log("okay step 2 done");
});
```

`Controller`

```
exports.add_item = (req, res, name, desc, price, stock, createdby) => {
  const Item = require('../models/item');
  const item = new Item(1, name, desc, price, stock, createdby);

  const response = item.save();

  if (response) {
    res.render('shopitemadded');
  } else {
    res.render('error');
  }
}
```

`NAV-Item`

```
<div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='dropbtn' id='shop' onclick="window.location.href='/shop';">Shop</button>
        <div class='dropdown-content'></div>
    </div>
```

`

Shop.ejs (View)
`

```
<body>
  <div class='nav-div'>
    <%- include('./partials/nav.ejs') %>
  </div>

  <div class='content' id='content-one'>
    <div class="grid">
      <%- include('./partials/item.ejs') %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='content' id='content-two'>
  </div>

  <div class='content' id='content-three'>
  </div>
</body>
```

`

Item.ejs (Partial View Element)
`

```
<% items.forEach(function(item) { %>
<div class="card"><img class="card__img" src="" alt="Canyons" />
  <div class="card__content">
    <h1 class="card__header"><%=item.name%></h1>
    <p class="card__text"><%=item.desc%></p>
    <form action="/shop/addtobasket" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="iditem" value="2" style="display: none;">
      <label for="amount">2
        <input type="text" name="amount" value="3">
      </label>
      <p>Anzahl an Lager: <%=item.stock%></p>
      <p>Stückpreis: <%=item.price%></p>
      <input class="card__btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Dem Warenkorb hinzufügen">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<% })%>
```

`

I am trying to set up a shop page. I did it the exact same way as all the other views (with a route and a controller). Only thing different: The ejs View has a partial (item.ejs) with a for each inside. Maybe I messed something up in there. Not sure.

Comment: I just realized. The item.ejs is definitely not the problem. The Shop page is not rendered in this part of my application. Sorry for the confusion. Must be something else

Comment: There was a ";" missing. But it was not the problem. Error still prevails. Need help

Comment: What is the exact error message? you're re-assigning value to a const. somewhere.